# Ember: recover data from dynamic "select" tags

Tags: forms, select, ember.js, controller

Using Ember, I am trying to build a form, with `<select>` droplists populated from stores. I don't know how to recover a value from here to use in a "save" function.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a simplified version of what I have :

1. The `route` accesses to differents models. This works fine :

   ```
   import Ember from 'ember';
   export default Ember.Route.extend({

       model() {
           var store = this.store;

           return Ember.RSVP.hash({
               fighters: store.findAll('fighter'),
               duels:store.findAll('duel')
           });
       },

       setupController(controller, models) {

           var fighters = models.fighters;
           var duels = models.duels;

           controller.set('fighters', fighters);
           controller.set('duels', duels);
      }
   });
   ```
2. The Controller should save a new duel using the form's values. Here "formdata" is null when the form is submitted

   ```
   import Ember from 'ember';
   export default Ember.Controller.extend({

       actions: {
           save(formdata) {
                var newduel = this.store.createRecord('duel', {
                     fighter1:formdata.fighter1,
                     fighter2:formdata.fighter2,
                });             
           }
       }
   });
   ```
3. The template displays droplists OK, but I cannot "connect" to the value in the controller, whatever `##FIGHTERn##` I try !

   ```
    <form {{action "save" formdata on "submit"}}>
   <dl>
       <dt>
           <select value='##FIGHTER1##'>
               {{#each fighters as |fighter|}}
                   <option value={{fighter.id}}>{{fighter.name}}</option> 
               {{/each}}
       </select>            
       </dt>

       <dt>
          <select value=##FIGHTER2##>
               {{#each fighters as |fighter|}}
                   <option value={{fighter.id}}>{{fighter.name}}</option> 
               {{/each}}
           </select>  
       </dt>
   </dl>
   <button type="submit">Add</button>
   ```

Comment: Have a look at this great blog post http://balinterdi.com/2015/08/29/how-to-do-a-select-dropdown-in-ember-20.html

Comment: The link given by @kiwiupover is the way you can manipulate your select list and get data to save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form {{action "save" formdata on "submit"}}>
<dl>
    <dt>
        <select onchange={{action (mut fighter1) value="target.value"}}>
            {{#each fighters as |fighter|}}
                <option value={{fighter.id}} selected={{is-equal fighter1 fighter.id}}>{{fighter.name}}</option> 
            {{/each}}
    </select>            
    </dt>

    <dt>
       <select onchange={{action (mut fighter2) value="target.value"}}>
            {{#each fighters as |fighter|}}
                <option value={{fighter.id}} selected={{is-equal fighter2 fighter.id}}>{{fighter.name}}</option> 
            {{/each}}
        </select>  
    </dt>
</dl>
<button type="submit">Add</button>
```

Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    actions: {
        save() {
            this.store.createRecord('duel', {
                fighter1: scope.get("fighter1"),
                fighter2: scope.("fighter2"),
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This can help you out